# Default syntax highlighting for HaXe questions

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Why doesn't the code in questions with [haxe](/questions/tagged/haxe) get syntax highlighting?

I've found some language tags for them in prettify which work when added.

For `hx` code,

```xml
<!-- language: lang-hx -->
```

For `hxml` and `nmml` files,

```xml
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
```

It would be nice to see all the posts with syntax highlighting.

***EDIT:***

Here's the extension file.

```js
/**
 * HaXe language binding for Google Code Prettifier
 *
 * @author Sri Harsha Chilakapati
 */
PR['registerLangHandler'](
    PR['createSimpleLexer'](
        [],
        [        
         // A double or single quoted, possibly multi-line, string.
         [PR['PR_STRING'],      /^(?:\'(?:[^\\\'\r\n]|\\.)*(?:\'|$)|\"(?:[^\\\"\r\n]|\\.)*(?:\"|$))/, null, '"\''],
         // A single line or multiline comment
         [PR['PR_COMMENT'],     /((?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:\/\/.*))|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//],
         // Keywords as per the list at haxe.org/ref/keywords along with data types
         [PR['PR_KEYWORD'],     /^(?:break|callback|case|cast|catch|class|continue|default|do|dynamic|else|enum|extends|extern|false|for|function|here|if|implements|import|in|inline|interface|never|new|null|override|package|private|public|return|static|super|switch|this|throw|trace|true|try|typedef|untyped|using|var|while|Void|Int|Float|Bool|String|Dynamic|#if|#else|#elseif|#end|trace)\b/, null],
         // Type names are class names starting with a capital letter
         [PR['PR_TYPE'],        /^\b(?:[@_]?[A-Z]+[a-z][A-Za-z_$@0-9]*|\w+_t\b)\b/],
         // All the punctuations
         [PR['PR_PUNCTUATION'], /[\.,-\/#!$%\?\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/],
         // Literal values are integers, or floats, or hex digits
         [PR['PR_LITERAL'],     /[0-9].?.+[0-9]+|[0-9]+|0x[a-fA-F0-9]+/]
        ]),
    ['hx', 'haxe']
);
```

Comment: For now, I just set [tag:haxe] to use default syntax highlighting instead of none. It will only affect HaXe questions that are not also tagged with a more specific tag such as [tag:javascript].

Comment: @mmyers You can include the javascript I posted as `lang-hx.js` and reference it. It's working for `pre` tags with class `lang-hx` or `lang-haxe`

Comment: I can't make a change like that; I'm only a moderator, not a developer.

Answer (score 4):

I [have submitted a feature request to Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=282&thanks=282&ts=1367215957).

SE just uses Google-prettify, and is not part of the development team. Please direct all future feature requests to their issue tracker.

---

Once it's fixed, ping a dev to update SE's local copy.

Comment: Worth to mention that SE is using a [local copy](http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/prettify-full.js?v=6c261bebf56a) so even after it's "fixed" the devs need to copy the new version to the servers.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: TIL. Thanks, updated :)

Comment: *ping a dev to update SE's local copy*, what do you mean? I don't understand that part.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati: See the comment above. SE hosts its own copy, if Prettify pushes an update SE needs to update their own copy. Not important now.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati "ping a dev" means either bump this request or find a dev in chat room and link to this post. Either case don't do it more than once the dev team has a lots on their hands and they don't owe us anything.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I've created the extension file and posted it in the issue.